# Filter pandas data frame on unique pair values

Tags: python, pandas, slice

I have a pandas data frame that contains information about games between two teams played at a different time:

```
TeamA   TeamB   Time

1   2   12:06
1   2   13.14
1   3   14.14
1   3   13.14
3   1   15.22
```

What is the simplest way (not double for loop) to obtain "sub" data frames that contain only the information about unique pairs of teams such as:

For (1,2):

```
TeamA   TeamB   Time

1   2   12:06
1   2   13.14
```

For (1,3):

```
TeamA   TeamB   Time

1   3   14.14
1   3   13.14
```

Etc.

**EDIT**:

I don't know in advance the teams that are present in the data frame. That is I'd need a data frame for every possible pair of teams.

Comment: Why isn't (3, 1) considered part of group 2?

Comment: Concatenate Team A and Team B in a certain helper column, for example into sorted list, then groupby on this helper column

Comment: (3,1) or (1,3) should also be in the same group, shouldn't?

Comment: Can you answer my question please? If not, then my answer is invalid, and I'd like to remove it. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you consider it as part of group 1

Comment: @NCL In that case, why haven't you looked at my answer? Please add that information in the question, it is very important, and you have just wasted jezrael's time.

Comment: Hmmm, my answer give solution for this requirement too ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create `dictionary of DataFrames`:

```
dfs = dict(tuple(df.groupby(['TeamA','TeamB'])))
print (dfs[(1,2)])
   TeamA  TeamB   Time
0      1      2  12:06
1      1      2  13.14
```

---

```
print (dfs[(1,3)])
   TeamA  TeamB   Time
2      1      3  14.14
3      1      3  13.14
```

If want all values:

```
for i, x in dfs.items():
    print (x)
   TeamA  TeamB   Time
0      1      2  12:06
1      1      2  13.14
   TeamA  TeamB   Time
2      1      3  14.14
3      1      3  13.14
   TeamA  TeamB   Time
4      3      1  15.22
```

If want last row in same group:

```
cols = ['TeamA','TeamB']
a = df[cols].apply(sorted, 1)
dfs = dict(tuple(df.groupby([a[cols[0]], a[cols[1]]])))

for i, x in dfs.items():
    print (x)
   TeamA  TeamB   Time
0      1      2  12:06
1      1      2  13.14

   TeamA  TeamB   Time
2      1      3  14.14
3      1      3  13.14
4      3      1  15.22
```

Comment: But I don't know in advance which teams are available

Comment: Then simply loop by dictionary, I add it to answer.

Comment: Thanks, that works well, but my doubt is if this is the best approach from a computational point of view/

Comment: Do you think if solution is very fast?

Comment: And for store multiple `DataFrame`s is `dictionary` very good choice.